# Windows Phone 7 Copy & Paste Support?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to allow my users to copy text from a textblock, and repaste it on a textbox.

How can I do this with my application?

Comment: I up-voted simply because someone else down-voted without a comment, which annoys me. You could probably be a bit more descriptive in what your trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

`Textblock` is not copy-paste-able. You can try using a `ReadOnly TextBox` as seen here: [WP7 CopyPaste on TextBlocks](http://sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/Windows-Phone-7-CopyPaste-on-TextBlocks.aspx)
.

You could also put it in a `WebBrowser` control (provided you have enough content and are willing to suffer the display / performance )